# How to sort the map based on value in c++ using stl?

Tags: c++, sorting, dictionary, stl, priority-queue

```
struct node{
    int index;
    int count;
};

map<int,struct node *> m1;

bool compare(struct node* a, struct node* b) {
    if(a->count>b->count)
        return 1;
    if(a->count==b->count && a->index<b->index)
        return 1;
    return 0;
}
```

Can i sort the map based on greater count value and if count is equal then based on lower index value?

A way is to push all the values in vector and perform sort. Is there any  other way by which sorting can be done using priority queue as below?

```
 priority_queue<pair<int,struct node *>, vector<int,struct node *>, compare> pq(m1.begin(),m1.end());
```

I have provided the compare function above.

Comment: `map` are sorted by key, not by value...

Comment: A map is already sorted, and it uses the Key (`int` in your case) to do this sorting.

Comment: You cannot `sort` a map.

Comment: Is there any way by which i can push the values of map in priority queue and sort?

Comment: Yes. If the map cannot change while you do this, you could push pointers to your values into a vector and sort.

Comment: How to do it using priority_queue priority_queue<pair<int,struct node *>, vector<int,struct node *>, compare> pq(m1.begin(),m1.end());  Correct me if i am wrong

Comment: What is the key in your map? Why not use a `std::set<node>` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution using priority_queue

```
  class compare {
    public:
        bool operator()(pair<int,struct node *> a, pair<int,struct node *> b)  {
         if(a.second->count>b.second->count)
            return 0;
        if(a.second->count==b.second->count && a.second->index<b.second->index)
            return 0;
        return 1;
        }
    };

   priority_queue<pair<int,struct node *>, vector<pair<int,struct node *> >, compare > pq(m1.begin(),m1.end());
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try using Boost [Multi-Index](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_39_0/libs/multi_index/doc/index.html). One index provides map access, the other provides ordered iterator access.